# how to debug golang cobra cli app in Goland

Tags: go, debugging, goland, cobra

how to debug golang cobra cli app in Goland

how to realize it in Goland or i give up by using VScode

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Include the actual code or output in your question, formatted as a code sample. There is formatting help available in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to either start the debugging session from the IDE or attach he debugger to a running process. You might want to take a look at these article for more details:[Starting a new debug session](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/starting-the-debugger-session.html),[Attaching to running process](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/attach-to-running-go-processes-with-debugger.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

According my understanding, you know how to debug Golang applications which do not involve cobra. For cobra applications, you need to specify the cli arguments in your Run/Debug configurations.

For example, ff you run your application in terminal with the command `./controller daemon -c config.yaml`, you will need to add "daemon -c config.yaml" in "Program arguments" field in your Run/Debug configurations.

[image: screenshot]